# Counter in java using timer scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, android

I use the code below to increase a counter every 1 second, but if the application is running a long time, the counter is going to infinite. What can I do?

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                time ++;
                ObservableObject.getInstance().updateValue(new TimerPojo(time,true));

            }
        },0,1000);
```

Comment: It won't go it infinite. It will go to 2 ^ 32-1. You can wrap the `Observable` line of code and set a limit (either time or number) then break the loop.

Comment: How long do you intend to run this? One minute is 60 seconds; on hour is 3,600 seconds; one day is 86,400 seconds; one week is 604,800 seconds. A java int hold up to 2,147,483,648. If you want to keep the program going for a long time, then use a long rather than an int as your counter.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right and there is no need to worry because the program runs for more than a few hours